# can't move text to the right in div

Tags: html, css

[image: This is how it suppose to look]

[image: and this is how it actually looks]

I tried many things such as `float: right;` but it doesnt work well. I also tried watching videos about it on youtube but coulnd find anything. How can I move biology, english, physics to the right side?

here is the code:

```css
courses {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.plates {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 512px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.course_icon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.full_course {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.course {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0rem 0rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 40px;
}

.course h3 {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="plates">
  <div class="full_course">
    <h2>Full Course</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/mathicon.png" alt="mth">
    <h3>Mathematics</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/his.png" alt="hi">
    <h3>History</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/chemis.png" alt="che">
    <h3>Chemistry</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/bio.png" alt="bi">
    <h3>Biology</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/en.png" alt="en">
    <h3>English</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/phys.png" alt="phy">
    <h3>Physics</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which element had `courses` class.

But, your problem can be solved using `display: grid`. See the lines with comment `/* CHANGE */`.

First element needs to be full width, so used `grid-column` property.
For rest of the elements, they need to be two elements on each row, so used `grid-template-columns`.

```css
.plates {
  display: grid;        /* CHANGE */
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;  /* CHANGE */
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 512px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.course_icon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.full_course {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1 / -1; /* OR grid-column-start: 1, grid-column-end: -1 */   /* CHANGE */
}

.course {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0rem 0rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 40px;
}

.course h3 {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="plates">
  <div class="full_course">
    <h2>Full Course</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/mathicon.png" alt="mth">
    <h3>Mathematics</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/his.png" alt="hi">
    <h3>History</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/chemis.png" alt="che">
    <h3>Chemistry</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/bio.png" alt="bi">
    <h3>Biology</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/en.png" alt="en">
    <h3>English</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/phys.png" alt="phy">
    <h3>Physics</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap those elements in a seperate div (otherwise the header would also be affected) and apply `column-count: 2` to that:

```css
courses {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.plates {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 512px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.columnwrapper {
  column-count: 2;
}
.course_icon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.full_course {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.course {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0rem 0rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 40px;
}

.course h3 {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="plates">
  <div class="full_course">
    <h2>Full Course</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="columnwrapper">
    <div class="course">
      <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/mathicon.png" alt="mth">
      <h3>Mathematics</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
      <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/his.png" alt="hi">
      <h3>History</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
      <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/chemis.png" alt="che">
      <h3>Chemistry</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
      <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/bio.png" alt="bi">
      <h3>Biology</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
      <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/en.png" alt="en">
      <h3>English</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="course">
      <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/phys.png" alt="phy">
      <h3>Physics</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   .courses {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.plates {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 512px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.course_icon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.plates h2 {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.course {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0rem 0rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 40px;
}

.course h3 {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="plates">
    <h2>Full Course</h2>
 <div class="courses">
      <div class="course-l">
          <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/mathicon.png" alt="mth">
    <h3>Mathematics</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/his.png" alt="hi">
    <h3>History</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/chemis.png" alt="che">
    <h3>Chemistry</h3>
  </div>
     
 </div>
<div class="course-r">
      <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/bio.png" alt="bi">
    <h3>Biology</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/en.png" alt="en">
    <h3>English</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="course">
    <img class="course_icon" src="Plate Icons/phys.png" alt="phy">
    <h3>Physics</h3>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.